# htaccess: how to redirect and then use mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a page

domain.com/project/all/

that I want to redirect to

domain.com/tasks/all/

But after this redirect I need it to apply a mod_rewrite to control some pagination querystring elements.

So domain.com/tasks/all/1/ etc

I have this

```
RewriteRule ^projects/all(.*)$ /tasks/all$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^tasks/all([/]*)([0-9]*)([/]*)$ /project-results.php?page=$2 [L]
```

But this does not appear to work as I expect it to (ie visibly redirect the user to tasks and then apply the second rule).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Provide some examples of how are you routing `/tasks/all/1/` internally to `/project-results.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `L` flag to your first rule:

```
RewriteRule ^projects/all(.*)$ /tasks/all$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^tasks/all([/]*)([0-9]*)([/]*)$ /project-results.php?page=$2 [L]
```

Otherwise, the first rule gets applied, changes the URI to `/tasks/all/...` and the request is flagged for an external redirect. Then the second rule also gets applied because the URI got changed, so it gets changed again, but the first rule already flagged it for an external redirect. Thus, you get redirected but to what the second rule targets.